# Does Pythonanywhere service support PostGIS?

Tags: database, postgresql, geospatial, postgis, pythonanywhere

I'd like to know whether it's possible to apply the spatial extension to PostgreSQL database in Pythonanywhere service or in other words if PostgreSQL is (or can be) installed with the PostGIS extension.

I looked around for official declaraions in the documentation (help, forum, etc.) but I only found it:

> ### What to do next
>
> That's up to you! We've tried to supply you with everything you could need, > including the bleeding-edge 9.4 version of Postgres, **PostGIS**, PL-Python and > PL-Python3.... Let us know how you get on! ([cit.](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/103/))

Thank you very mutch
Cheers

Manuele

Comment: It seems to me that the statement you pasted in is pretty clear

Comment: Yes it is, indeed.